# Transforming a GeoPackage table's geometry column into GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, sqlite, geopackage

I have a GeoPackage that is downloaded to client devices for a mobile app. I need the clients to query the GeoPackage to retrieve a GeoJSON representation of the `geom` column. I'm familiar with `ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)` available in PostGIS, but I cannot find a similar solution using a GeoPackage.

How can I transform the `geom` column into GeoJSON? Ideally it would be in a query, but if that's not available I'd like to know how to convert the `geom` binary myself programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

On mobile there is geopackage iOS and Android from the US Government NGA. You can also use geopackage-js API and use javascript for the conversion. But why convert it why not render the vector features on the map ? Geopackage native lets you do this as raster tiles on the fly.  my app is doing that